The choice of vector potential for a Hexagonal lattice in magnetic field?
I am interested in the problem of a hexagonal lattice placed into a homogeneous magnetic field perpendicular to the lattice plane. My question is about the choices of the magnetic field and vector potential for this problem so that we get a periodic structure and can define a magnetic unit cell.
For instance, for the square lattice problem in a perpendicular magnetic field, we use the Landau gauge for vector potential; also, we know that if the flux per square is a rational ($\frac mn$) multiple of flux quantum, we get a periodic structure in which the unit cell contains $n$ squares.
Can someone please introduce some references in which I can find information about the periodic magnetic Hexagonal lattice and its magnetic unit cell?
